# change ios5 device brightness when application in background mode

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I want to user notify that some event is fired so that i used brightness 
**[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 1.0// 0.0** alternatively
It is work fine when apps in foreground mode but 
when application is background mode and that event is fired at that time my code is not working.
i used location so my application is able to run in background.

Give me suggestion how to set brightness when application is in background mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

   // UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier *bgTask = nil;
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];


    counterTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                       [app endBackgroundTask:counterTask]; 
                       counterTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

                       // If you're worried about exceeding 10 minutes, handle it here  
                       theTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20
                                                                 target:self
                                                               selector:@selector(YourFunction)
                                                               userInfo:nil
                                                                repeats:YES];
                   }];

    count=0;
    theTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(YourFunction)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES]; 

    //[super viewDidLoad];

}
```